# find all recently modified (ctime) files that are not located in multiple excluded directories

Tags: grep, find, ubuntu-14.04

During the course of troubleshooting a Ubuntu package reconfiguration I ran across the need to list which files had been modified during the course of the automatic reconfiguration, to find out what files the reconfiguration changed to make the software work. Got software that runs as intended on one server, but does not run as intended on the cloned server, go figure.

Came up with the following find statement that does not produce the desired result.

```
find / -type f -ctime -1 | egrep -v '(/proc|/run|/sys|/var/lib/apt)'
```

Many recently modified (ctime) files are unnecessarily listed under the /run /proc /sys /var/lib/apt directories when executing the command.

Also, does find offer a ctime minute designation? To specify, within the last 2 minutes.  The options above, `-ctime -1`, specified within the last hour: no good for troubleshooting installs that take 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding results from a `find` command is usually done with its `-prune` action :

```
find / \( -path /proc -or -path /run -or -path /sys -or -path /var/lib/apt \) -prune ,\
     -type f -ctime -1 -print
```

To search for files modified in the last minutes, use the `-cmin` option instead of `-ctime`.

```
find / \( -path /proc -or -path /run -or -path /sys -or -path /var/lib/apt \) -prune ,\
     -type f -cmin -2 -print
```

Comment: My -ctime -1 returns files going back 24 hours instead of just an hour ago.  Is there a command line switch combination that will report files with a ctime within the past 5 minutes?

Comment: You can use `-cmin` instead of `-ctime`, it accepts minutes instead of days

Comment: I tried it. -cmin is definitely what I needed. Thank you Aaron, your a linux god, don't let your in-laws tell you any different !

Comment: find / \( -path /proc -or -path /run -or -path /sys -or -path /var/lib/apt -or -path /var/log -or -path /var/lib -or -path /var/cache \) -prune , -type f -cmin -1  This find / exclude command really filters out all the files that are always changing. Makes troubleshooting much easier.